# marionettejs attachhtml ie8 - unexpected call to method or property

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, marionette

I'm testing my site in IE8. I'm using MarionetteJS and I have views dynamically added to the page.

My page breaks in the marionette.js code on this line:

```
this.el.appendChild(view.el);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this? Sorry if it's a little vague, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve exactly ?

Comment: Well @KavishDwivedi I don't understand why marionette won't append a region to the page. It is crashing at appendChild in only IE8, but not other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was using Boilerplate MVC and it was a  `header`  tag that was being used, which Marionette with IE8 didn't particularly like. Once I replaced the header with a  `div` , IE8 worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the problem in this case is the html5 tag, not really Marionette.  But if you use https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv you can use html5 tags with no issue in IE8 with Marionette.

Comment: This actually is a useful shim/polyfill

Answer (score 0):

What jQuery version are you using?
You need a legacy build (the 1.* versions) for Internet Explorer 8.